# SQL SELECT and UPDATE at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple SELECT looking like this:

```
SELECT path FROM items WHERE id = 17
```

Now in the table `items` there is also a column `count`, which I want to have incremented everytime the above query is executed.

What is the optimal way to do this?

Comment: Thats a weird request

Comment: I don't think you can do in a query, you may need to write a procedure for this.

Comment: If you want to do in a single query, can't you do a select inside an update? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955988/mysql-select-inside-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do that in same query.

You can do something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ....
SELECT ....
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a stored procedure and then create an atomic transaction using

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE items set count = (SELECT MAX(count)+1 from items);
SELECT path FROM items WHERE id = 17;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

try combining the update and select into a single call, the response from the SELECT should be returned

```
UPDATE items SET count = count + 1; SELECT path FROM items WHERE id = 17
```